# Jquery zoom IE7 css absolute positioning error

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

I am using a [JQuery plug-in for image zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/), which is not working properly in IE7, The position of zoomed image is different.

**in Firefox:**

[image]

**in  IE7**

[image]

```
<span class="zoom" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<img  width="100px" height="100px" src="../gallery/sample/pic.jpg">
<img class="zoomImg" src="../gallery/sample/pic.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: -321px; left: -277.5px; opacity: 0; width: 420px; height: 336px; border: medium none; max-width: none;">
</span>


.zoom{display:inline-block,margin:10px;}
.zoomImg{z-index:5;}
```

Comment: This is a z-index problem as IE7 handles z-index stacking context differently to other browsers. Could you quickly make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so I can see all the code?

Comment: Try `<span class="zoom" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<img  width="100px" height="100px" style="z-index: 1;" src="../gallery/sample/pic.jpg">
<img class="zoomImg" style="z-index: 2;" src="../gallery/sample/pic.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: -321px; left: -277.5px; display: hidden; width: 420px; height: 336px; border: medium none; max-width: none;">
</span>`

Comment: @AdamBotley Had tried assigning z-indices values for parent and children, tried `position:relative;`,tried `zoom:1` but nothing works yet.

Comment: The `opactiy` creates a seperate stacking context in IE7, try removing that.

Comment: `opacity` is needed for the plugin

Answer (score 0):

The `display:inline-block` CSS statement displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box. Try to play around with this, it is known bug in IE7 and earlier with this property.

One more thing, as stated on the plug-in website: *Compatible with: jQuery 1.7+ in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer 7+.* So, apparently the plug-in works in browser  above IE7 .

Answer (score 0):

So, IE is fun. IE7 and older handle z-index slightly differently to newer browsers ([Reference](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/)).

In IE7, each element with an assigned z-index creates a new **stacking context**. This means any elements z-index nested within it are stacking in relation to the parent element. 
A simple example:

```
<div id="container-one" style="z-index: 1;">
    <p id="para-one" style="z-index: 99999;">Paragraph One</p>
</div>
<div id="container-two" style="z-index: 2;">
    <p id="para-two" style="z-index: 1;">Paragraph Two</p>
</div>
```

In this example, `#para-two` would be above `#para-one`. *"But `#para-one` has a huge z-index, it must be above everything"*. `#container-one` has a z-index lower than `#container-two`. They are now **separate stacking contexts**.

`#para-one`'s z-index is only in relation to everything *within* `#container-one`. 
Also, for extra **fun**, `opacity` creates a new stacking context as well!!

Ok, for your code, I had to guess a little as to what the full html was because you **didn't make a FIDDLE!!!**. I got it working here in IE7, just to give you an idea as to what you need to change.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK5Ss/)

I've set the `.zoomImg` to have a z-index higher than it's sibling `.div` elements. Note, I removed `opacity` and added a `z-index` instead. This is to forcefully assign a higher `z-index`. You can put it back in, but remember **`opacity` creates a new stacking context in IE7**. That means if you give an element an `opacity`, it's `z-index` and it's children are seperate from it's current context. Welcome to IE7, have a nice time.

EDIT: IE7 needs a different property for opacity --

`filter: alpha(opacity=50);` - [SOURCE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

Comment: +1 nice explanation, But what is the solution? How you make para-two appear before para-one? and the issue is not only abt the z-index. the `position:absolute` is not rendering as desired in IE :(

Comment: Edited for your pleasure

Comment: uhmm adam, its a plugin that requires opacity, and also the zooming is not static like in your fiddle, AND I didn't create a fiddle coz I doubt fiddle can replicate my scenario of auto generating a photo gallery from sever side, even the scripting is done at the backend.

Comment: I created the fiddle as a simple example of how to organise the z-indexing, based of what I'm *guessing* the HTML looks like. Without more information, I've done all I can

Answer (score -1):

Try [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/). If it does not work, simply forget about supporting this outdated and buggy browser.

Comment: "Simply forget IE7". If someone is trying to get something working on IE7, there's a very good chance they don't have a choice. There's always a workaround without having to resort to giving up or bloating your code with plugins and polyfills.

Comment: @AdamBotley Trying, in late 2013, to get complex z-index-based JQuery effects to work on IE7 is a sure way of losing time, hair and sanity. I'm just saying.

Comment: I had to do it a few weeks ago. Read a couple of articles on it and with a little extra work it's fine.